# How to check pending queue message on embedded ActiveMQ Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic

I'm trying to send message using ActiveMQ broker. When I am using external ActiveMQ I am able to check my queue messages status like pending, consumed, and the content of messages also using webconsole.
[image]

Is it possible to check my queue message status while I am using embedded ActiveMQ on Spring Boot?

Comment: just want to more clear about the question, Do you want to check how many messages you send to queue and how many are delivered or not delivered yet?

Comment: yes @RahulKumar , like information on the webconsole while using external activemq